# iOS React Native App/ Build Succeeded but App not getting open in iOS device/ Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, xcode11.3

iOS App is build successfully but App is not getting open in the Simulator or device.

Getting chmod error for the app path.

Error:

```
info ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

info Installing <PATH TO APP>.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Could not install at this time.
Failed to chmod /Users/surabhiagrawal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7A54A41E-006C-4B29-B33A-BE956F715255/data/Bundle/Application/0A68FDA4-1D57-49BB-8377-7BA5AC9BBB46/<AppName> : No such file or directory
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
    Failed to chmod /Users/surabhiagrawal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7A54A41E-006C-4B29-B33A-BE956F715255/data/Bundle/Application/0A68FDA4-1D57-49BB-8377-7BA5AC9BBB46/<AppName>.app/<AppName> : No such file or directory
info Launching <Package Name>
com.goshopmatic.ShopmaticGoApp: -1
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "App Package name" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application <App_Path_Name> is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "App package name" is unknown to FrontBoard.
    Application "App package name" is unknown to FrontBoard.
```

Comment: try clean & build project again

Comment: its not working out. i tried

Comment: Did you get this working? I am seeing the same error.

Comment: The same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading XCode.